# update html session R

Tags: curl, rvest, httr

I am trying to update html session and move to the second page in website, but i get an error: Navigating to javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UCNested$grdRTAList','Page$2')
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Port number ended with '_'

```
library(rvest)
url <- "http://rtais.wto.org/UI/PublicMaintainRTAHome.aspx"
pgsession <- html_session(url) %>% follow_link(css = 
"#ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkRTAList") # List of all RTAs in force
pgsession <- pgsession %>% 
follow_link(xpath = "//table[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_UCNested_grdRTAList']//a[.='2']")
```